# Is there a way to include external files in final Eclipse plugin product?

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, product, eclipse-neon

I'm working on a project which uses eclipse (neon) as base, enriching it with some plugins.
Acutally one of my plugins is using an executable located in a portable version of a software (that's because the final usere is not allowed to install things as administrator).

I would like to avoid copying the folder inside the sources file every times, maybe finding a way to copy it automatically when building the product.
Can anyone help me?

Note that I can't switch my eclipse version.

What I tried:

1) Add it as a source folder by selecting:
Project -> Properties -> Java build Path

2) include it into the build properties of the plugin that I use to export the product

Here are the steps I follow to create the product:

1) I have a plugin containing all the informations to build my project, than I select it an click on "Eclipse Product Export Wizard" into the Overview tab.

[image: Step 1]

2) I'm using the settings in the following image:

[image: Step 2]

3) the finla output is:

[image: What I get]

what I would like to have at the end is something like:

[image: What I need]

with the folder "Resources" containing all the extra files (in this case a portable software)

Thank you.

Dylan

Comment: Use a Feature based build and use the various root directives in the feature's build.properties. See [this](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpde_feature_generating_build.htm) and [this](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_rootfiles.htm)

Comment: @greg-449
I switched to a feature based build, and tried to use: root=/resources/  or   root=D:\resources  into the build.properties file but anything is showing up in my final product...
am I missing something??

Comment: That doesn't look like the correct syntax. Read the descriptions and examples [here](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_rootfiles.htm) carefully.

Comment: I think I am missing something about the syntax, expecially the keywords...
I tried to copy-paste several lines  and istructions (obviusly inserting my own path)  but I still can't figure out how to make that work... 
Is there a site which explains how the syntax works?? so I can learn how it works instead of copying it...

Comment: That help entry is the main resource. Just specifying `root=resources` will copy a `resources` folder from the feature directory to the build root directory.